# Apache httpd: interaction of If and Require directives

Tags: apache-2.4

What exactly can you put inside an `<If>` directive, and how does it affect any enclosed `Require` statements?

The test config below is intended to serve two files (`/var/www/data/foo.txt` and `/var/www/data/bar.txt`). `apachectl configtest` reports it as valid. However, it only serves foo.txt, and says that bar.txt is forbidden - why?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/data
  <Directory /var/www/data>
    require all denied

    # works
    <Files "foo.txt">
      <If true>
        require all granted
      </If>
    </Files>

    # doesn't work    
    <If true>
      <Files "bar.txt">
        require all granted
      </Files>
    </If>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```